# Существует ли возможность «сблюрить» (эффект — blur) изображение средствами PHP?

Tags: jquery, html, php, javascript

Привет, сейчас очень моден эффект блюра, как на iOS7. Реализовываю двумя картинками, одной полноценной, другой уже «сблюренной» фотошопом. Неудобство в том что клиенту, когда меняет их в админке, нужно готовить сразу две картинки что его напрягает.

Пришла идея:

```
1) искать все <img/> с классом .blur
2) отдавать аяксом урл картинки пхп скрипту
3) применять эффект на сервере
4) отдавать картинку на клиент
5) обернуть все <img/> в <div> вместе с принятым изображением
```

Собственно вопросы:

```
1) Насколько это «костыли», по Вашему мнению? (понимаю что вопрос риторический)
2) как реализовать пункт 3 и 4?
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть в GD функция [`imagefilter()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imagefilter.php), вот нашёл вам примеры использования: `http://blog.dubbelboer.com/2012/12/09/php-image-blur.html`

Может, как вариант, сделать на CSS или SVG: `http://css-plus.com/2012/03/gaussian-blur/`